# Copy values from one array to other array without using pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, arrays, memory, misra

I'm using this function to copy some values from one array to other array:

```
void *copy_array(const void *src, void *dest, uint8 pos, uint8 len, uint8 elemsize)
{
   const unsigned char *csrc = src;

   memcpy(dest, csrc + (pos * elemsize), len * elemsize);
}
```

Is there any similar way to do this without using pointer arithmetic? MISRA suggests to avoid pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `memcpy(dest, &csrc[pos*elemsize], len * elemsize);`

Comment: There is no good reason to avoid pointer arithmetic in this code if it is to be used in production software. Is this an exercise for a class? If so, what is the actual problem statement? There are different conceptual levels on which “pointer arithmetic” can be considered to be taking place—an explicit expression in C source code, an implicit expression such as an array reference, and at the machine level. At the latter level, it is impossible to avoid pointer arithmetic, since the memory address is needed to load the data and therefore it **must** be calculated. What is the real problem?

Comment: It is to be used in production SW. But some specific rules, like the automotive coding MISRA rules says that pointer arithmetic shall be avoided if possible.

Comment: The answer depends on the level of "similarity" you require ;-) If you need misra compliance I'd recommend avoiding anything accepting or returning `void*` if possible.

Comment: Exactly, it is regarding MISRA compliance :)

Comment: Well, then read Rule 11.5 - it is "only" Advisory, but... you'll need a good argument why you absolutely had to use `void*`, and that you can prove that all pointers are actually correctly aligned etc.

Comment: IMO the main problem here is having void pointers in the first place.

Comment: Is it necessary at your task to provide a general-use function instead of a type specific one? You could save some handle and also make it more safe.

Comment: C code can't be type safe AND generic, so you have to choose one - and if you need MISRA compliance, the choice is not yours - the sad answer is, you can't implement this helper function in a safe way.

Comment: Basically, the MISRA rules do not want you screwing around with pointer arithmetic because you might muck it up. But this routine is passed **only** addresses, element sizes, and element indices. That means it **cannot** do its work without calculating addresses (directly or indirectly), and anybody who calls it has already run the risk MISRA wants to avoid, by decomposing their high-level objects (such as an array of known type) into pieces such as element sizes. About the best you might do in this routine is `const uint8 (*x)[elemsize] = src; memcpy(dest, &x[pos], len * sizeof *x);`.

Comment: But I would not be surprised if MISRA has a rule against variable length array types, in which case the above is not allowed.

Comment: The main rationale behind the MISRA rule is to get rid of `*(arr + i)` and favour `arr[i]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil MISRA-C:2012 does indeed have a rule (18.8) against using any form of VLA. Far too strict in my opinion, they should allow pointers to VLA.

Answer (score 1):

For MISRA compliance, simply do `memcpy(dest, &csrc[pos * elemsize], len * elemsize);`.

Though I don't quite understand why you need a function for this, instead of just calling `memcpy` directly. As mentioned in comments, MISRA frowns at the use of void pointers through advisory rules, since mission-critical software should be deterministic, not generic.

Also, `len * elemsize` is rather questionable, since this would limit the function to arrays of maximum 255 bytes.

You could potentially avoid a lot of MISRA problems by converting the function to a function-like macro. Not necessarily an improvement readability-wise, but as far as I remember this should be MISRA compliant:

```
#define copy_array(src, dst, pos, len, elemsize) \
  memcpy((dst), &(src)[(pos)*(elemsize)], (len)*(elemsize))
```